# How to get a string representation of an audio AVStream in ffmpeg?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavformat

I'm using `ffmpeg`. Consider the following piece of code:

```
for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            //how do I get the language of the stream?          
        }
}
```

I found out that there is a `LangEntry` struct in `libavformat` ([avlanguage file](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/avlanguage.c)), there's also a table containing languages and their codes, seems it's just what I need. But I don't know how to use it. I couldn't find any examples of its usage. There are no reference to the `LangEntry` neither in `AVStream`, nor in `AVCodecContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LangEntry has nothing to do with your objective of detecting the language.
In fact, LangEntry table is to do with [List of ISO 639-2 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes)

Language code gets encoded as metadata, so you should be trying as below to identify the language

```
AVDictionaryEntry *lang;  
for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) 
{
    if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) 
    {
       lang = av_dict_get(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->metadata, "language", NULL,0);
       // Check lang->value, it should give 3-letter word matching to one of the LangEntry Table
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get subtitles type (subrip or ass)? other metadata (rather than language)? also where is info about all those strings like "language" and so on?